# Typeguard using multiple sub-types' property type

Tags: typescript, generics, typeguards

### Edit (Clarification)

I do admit I was not clear about the issue. I apologize.

As pointed out, in most cases I wouldn't even need `fruitTypes`. But the problem is that fruits behave like a weird variation of OOP where `Fruit` act as an object, but not allowed to have mutability nor impure functions.

Perhaps traditional OOP design pattern would do this:

```typescript
abstract class Fruit {
    abstract name: string
}

class Apple extends Fruit {
    name:string
    brand:"AppleCo"|"iApple"

    constructor(name:string,brand:"AppleCo"|"iApple") {
        super()
        this.name = name
        this.brand = brand
    }

    doAppleStuff() {
        if(this.brand === "iApple") {
            console.log("Evil company alert")
            this.name += ": EVIL!"
            return
        }
        
        return "DONE"
    }
}

const fruits:Fruit[] = [new Apple("GoodApple", "AppleCo") /* orange, peach, pear... */]

fruits
  .filter((fruit) : fruit is Apple => !!fruit )
  .forEach(apple=>apple.doAppleStuff())
```

But the problem is that it creates so many mutations and impure functions. I don't want to put methods (static, pure, impure, whatever) in type either. So ideally I would rather:

```typescript
// Immutable types.
type Fruit = {
    fruitType:"Apple"|"Orange"
}

type Orange = Fruit & {
    name:string
    acidity:number
}

// Pure functions
function makeAcidBomb(orange:Orange, props:{using:number}) : {orangeAfter:Orange, bomb?:Bomb} {
    if(orange.acidity < props.using) {
        console.log("Not acid enough")
        return {orangeAfter:{...orange}, bomb:undefined}
    }

    const newAcidity = orange.acidity - props.using

    return {
        orangeAfter: {
            ...orange,
            acidity:newAcidity
        },
        bomb: {
            acidity:orange.acidity
        }
    }
}

const bombMaker = (orange:Orange) => makeAcidBomb(orange, {using:.25})

const orange:Orange = {
  fruitType:"Orange",
  acidity:.25,
  name:"bad orange",
}

const fruits:Fruit[] = [orange, /*apple, peach, pear...*/]

const results = fruits
  .filter(fruit => fruit.fruitType === "Orange")
  .forEach(orange =>  bombMaker(orange as Orange))
```

All fine and dandy. But think of the situation where the codebase requires hundreds of fruits to maintain. At some point it will become too tedious to check all that manually:

```typescript
function *yieldEdibleSmoothieProductionProcess(fruits:Fruit[]) {
  yield "PRODUCTION STARTS!"

  for (const fruit of fruits.values()) {
      if(isEdible(fruit)) {
          yield {operation:"MIX", fruit}
          continue
      }
      
      yield {operation:"DISCARD",fruit}
  }

  yield {operation:"BLEND"}
  yield "DONE!"
}

function isEdible(fruit:Fruit, world:World) {
  // Fruits do not have common properties for edibility, for example fruit.canEat,
  // Because there might be a case where it needs complex logics to determine if it is really edible or not.
  // But also, they are not allowed to have methodes, so you can not rely on fruit.isEdible() either.
  // Because of this, you need to know what fruit it would be, then call functions that fits.

  if(fruit === "Orange")
      return isOrangeEdible(fruit as Orange, world)
  
  if (fruit === "Apple")
      return isAppleEdible(fruit as Apple)

  // and follows train of hundred if statements for different Fruits as well as `===` comparison and `as` castings.
  // if (fruit === "Pear")
  // if (fruit === "Kiwi")
  // if (fruit === "Banana")
  // if (fruit === "Peach")

  return true
}

// simple logic
function isAppleEdible(apple:Apple) {
  return true // Apple is always edible!
}

// complex logic
function isOrangeEdible(orange:Orange, world:World) {
  if(orange.poisonedWithAgentOrange && world.evilPatricideCompanyExists)
      return false
  return true
}

const fruits = [apple,orange,pear,peach,banana,melon,lemon]
const smootheProcess = [...yieldEdibleSmoothieProductionProcess(fruits)]
```

If fruits were class objects, it would have been easy. just put `<Fruit>` generics and check them by `instance of`. Or just implement abstract `.isEdible()` and do whatever it needs to be done. But in this weird case I need `fruitType` to do so.

I'm not convinced that I have to manually maintain long long list of `"Apple"|"Peach"|"Pear"|"Banana"|...` and risk a human error. I COULD check them without long list of all possible fruit types, but then I have no benefit of autocompletion as IDE has no idea what `fruitType` would be.

As of writing I started to think that my 'design' as a whole might have more fundamental problems. If it is, please don't hesitate to criticize me. Thank you.

--- End of edit.

### Problem

Type `Fruit` is 'base' type of `Apple` and `Orange` subtype, like so:

```typescript
type Fruit = {
    name:string,
}

type Apple = Fruit & {
    name:"apple",
}

type Orange = Fruit & {
    name:"orange",
    acidity:.5,
}
```

Now, suppose I have to determine whether a `Fruit` object is `Apple` or not:

```typescript
function isApple(fruit:Fruit) {
    if (fruit instanceof Apple) // this won't work.
        return "APPLE"

    return "NOT APPLE"
}
```

Clearly `instanceof` fails, so now I have to add sort of 'type id' for each subtypes like so:

```typescript
type Fruit = {
    fruitType:string, // unique id for each subtypes.
    name:string,
}

type Apple = Fruit & {
    fruitType:"APPLE", // unique id 
    name:"apple",
}

type Orange = Fruit & {
    fruitType:"ORANGE", // unique id 
    name:"orange",
    acidity:.5,
}

function isApple(fruit:Fruit) {
    if (fruit.fruitType === "APPLE") // success
        return "APPLE"

    return "NOT APPLE"
}
```

The problem is that I'm forced to manually maintain the list of `fruitType` from now on. For example, If I were to use generics:

```typescript
type FruitType = "APPLE"|"ORANGE"

type Fruit<FruitType> = {
    fruitType:FruitType,
    name:string,
}

type Apple = Fruit<"APPLE"> & {
    name:"apple",
}

type Orange = Fruit<"ORANGE"> & {
    name:"orange",
    acidity:.5,
}

function isApple(fruit:Fruit<FruitType>) {
    if (fruit.fruitType === "APPLE")
        return "APPLE"

    return "NOT APPLE"
}
```

That's fine. But I'd rather:

```typescript
// Get all types that extends `Fruit`, and gather their `type` property type.
// In this case, it would be: "APPLE"|"ORANGE"
type AllPossibleFruitTypes = AllPropertyTypesOfTypesThatExtends<Fruit, "type">

type Fruit = {
    type:AllPossibleFruitTypes,
    name:string,
}

type Apple = Fruit & {
    type:"APPLE",
    name:"apple",
}

type Orange = Fruit & {
    type:"ORANGE",
    name:"orange",
    acidity:.5,
}

// No need to manually update fruitTypes.

function isApple(fruit:Fruit) {
    if (fruit.type === "APPLE")
        return "APPLE"

    return "NOT APPLE"
}
```

### Question

I do understand I could just use `class` and call it a day. But I wonder if there is a way to do this using types and typeguard.

Comment: `instanceof` operator tests to see if the prototype property of a constructor appears anywhere in the prototype chain of an object. Hence, it might be unsafe if you use inheritance, but if not, you can use it in a simple cases. See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

Comment: There's no way to ask the compiler to inspect your code base to see all the named types that extend another type.  You'll have to encode your assumptions about which types you will run into, and that looks like a single manually maintained union somewhere in your code.  I don't see why that's a problem; could you [edit] to explain?  It really seems like you should be using [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMBDkW) instead of generics...

Comment: ...especially because checking for `Orange` given an object of your `Fruit` type would require checking `acidity` explicitly (after all, there's no guarantee that a `Fruit` whose `name` is `"orange"` actually has any other properties). If `Fruit` were a discriminated union with `name` as a discriminant, most of your desired behavior falls out by checking `name`. If you want me to write any of this up as an answer, let me know. Or if I'm missing something.  (Pls mention @jcalz in a comment if you reply, to notify me.)

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for your input. I actually hesitated to notify you since technically you've already answered my question succinctly. I understand there really is no way to, say, 'meta-typeguard' the type. But after some edit, now it feels like it have become an entirely different question. If you perhaps share some of your insights for my problem. it will be more than helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)? In this example you would refactor the condition into a type predicate:

```
function isThisAnApple(fruit: Fruit): fruit is Apple {
    return fruit.name === "apple";
}

function isApple(fruit: Fruit) {
    if (isThisAnApple(fruit)) {
        fruit; // now type is `Apple`

        return "NOT APPLE";
    }

    return "APPLE";
}
```